# How to use ShinyStartup in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to setup a Bluetooth device manager. I came across this tutorial(https://www.xamboy.com/2020/04/20/bluetooth-printing-in-xamarin-forms-using-shiny/) that uses a the Shiny Nuget. I Keep getting the following error: 'function1' does not implement inherited abstract member 'function2'. My code is shown bellow.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Shiny;

namespace BTShin
{
    public class ShinyAppStartup : ShinyStartup
    { 
        public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.UseBleCentral();
            services.UseBlePeripherals();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are these compiler errors or runtime exceptions?  Which specific line causes the error?  What does the stack trace show?  Did you read the official docs and follow the necessary steps?

Comment: Where does the error occur exactly? Post the complete error.

Comment: public class ShinyAppStartup : ShinyStartup <- this line causes the error

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: CS0534: 'ShinyAppStartup does not implement inherited abstract member 'ShinyStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection,IPlatform)'

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your not implementing the correct version of 'ConfigureServices'.

The latest version takes a second IPlatform parameter -> https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny/blob/4a33eb5d94bc3a8023b18405fef06fecc8d25110/src/Shiny.Core/ShinyStartup.cs#L37

Looks like the docs are out of date

```
public abstract void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IPlatform platform);
```